# Asynctask cant run twice

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-button

I have a problem when I'm trying to run an `AsyncTask` several times. Here is my code:

```
btnonoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (btnonoff.isChecked()){
            new main_progress_doinbackground().execute();

                   }
            }
       });
   }
```

I want to execute the `AsyncTask` whenever I check the toggle button. The first time the code executes fine, but when I try to run it again, it's not working. I think it's because `main_progress_doinbackground().execute();` can't stop. I tried to stop it manually but the problem exist...

This id my Asynctask code :

```
class main_progress_doinbackground extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
dodb();
return null;
```

dodb() get some gps locations and if they are near the device , it began to alarm .

```
new main_progress_doinbackground().cancel(true);
main_progress_doinbackground.cancel(true);
```

both not working .

I tried this but it's not working. When I use this code :

```
btnonoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!btnonoff.isChecked()) {
        //      new main_progress_doinbackground().cancel(true);
                main_progress_doinbackground.cancel(true);

            }

        if (btnonoff.isChecked()){

        //new main_progress_doinbackground().execute();
         main_progress_doinbackground.execute();
```

I gave this error :

> 11-15 08:30:05.065: E/AndroidRuntime(1458):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is
>   already running.

Comment: Please define "its not working". Please post the code to `main_progress_doinbackground`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks bro , i edited my post . please check it again .

Comment: did you debug with a breakpoint your code? are you sure about your "cant stop"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your AsyncTask object and cancel the specific one. Change your code like that:

```
main_progress_doinbackground myTask;
btnonoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myTask = new main_progress_doinbackgroud;
            if (btnonoff.isChecked()){
            myTask.execute();

                   }
            }
       });
   }
```

And when you want to stop that task:

```
myTask.cancel(true);
```

Note: As an advice, follow good programming practices, change your class name `main_progress_doinbackground` to `MainProgressTask`. That turns your object definition into this:

```
MainProgressTask mainProgressTask;
```

Comment: thanks , i note that , i changed my codes like yours  but the problem stiil exist .

Comment: are you sure you are calling cancel() with the exact same object on which you called execute()?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem happens because you are calling the .execute() method over the same instance of your AsynckTask, and you can't do this. 
More exactly:

wrong way

```
// only one instance
MyAsinchTask myAsynchTask = new MyAsinchTask();

myAsynchTask.execute();
myAsynchTask.execute();
```

correct way

```
// two different instances
MyAsinchTask myAsynchTask = null;

myAsynchTask = new MyAsinchTask();  // first instance
myAsynchTask.execute();

myAsynchTask = new MyAsinchTask();  // second instance
myAsynchTask.execute();             // error!
```

try to correct your code, making sure you create a new instance every time you invoke the execute() method.

P.S.: read this simple article about code and naming convention in Java! It's very important!
[basic Java code convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)